# javascript - read binary file and make a string from it

Tags: javascript, file, binary

I have a php script that generates a binary file (is some kind of compression of a map, doesn't really matter).
I can save it as an image for example and send it.

What I need now is to make a string from that file. To be more clear... I want to get the bits (ignore the image overhead of course) and the final string must be something like 100101010101111... u get the idea.

Can and if yes how do I do this in javascript?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Storing each bit as a character isn't base64. And it's much less efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an AJAX call to retrieve the contents of the file and then use bitwise operators to generate the binary representation string that you are striving for.

*The php script must be accessible through a HTTP request, of course.*

One of the easiest ways to implement a AJAX GET request is to use `jQuery.get`, which you can read more about [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Regarding the generation of a binary representation there are several implementations available online.

I wrote my own sample implementation of a string to binary converter:

```
var data          = "h€llo world ";
var binary_string = "";

for (var idx in data) {
  var v = data.charCodeAt (idx);

  do {
    var b = v & 0xFF;

    for (var i =0; i < 8; ++i)
      binary_string += (b & (1<<(7-i))) ? '1' : '0';

    binary_string += ' ';

  } while (v >>= 8);
}
```

binary_string = `01101000 10101100 00100000 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100 00100000`